# How do I set my root account in mysql to be accessed locally?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I am running into a bit of a problem here. I have a mysql server setup on an Ubuntu 12.04 distro. After the initial install I have been using MySQL Workbench to do all my db creation and administrative tasks such as backup\restore etc.

**My MySQL Version:**

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
```

So now we are trying to automate the backup with a custom service. I logged in with putty to the server and tried to login to the MySQL shell using this format.

```
myuser@skydb1:~$ mysqldump -u root -p mydb
Enter password:
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Initially I went back and tried to re-authenticate with the Workbench to make sure I was using the correct credentials and I was. Going back to the server and attempting to login via the shell I got the same error.

In the screenshot below you can see that the Workbench indicates that the root user has all appropriate privileges.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfvR9.png

**EDIT 1**

The password was removed.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: Login via Workbench and show us the output of `show grants for 'root'@'localhost'`?

Comment: Are you sure that password is the same with `'root'@'%'`?

Comment: That is a good question. I don't think I went through and verified they were all the same. Now if I am not mistaken the password that is shown in the above query is not the actual password? It is just a hashed password correct?

Comment: That did it! I went through and reset the password on every root account showing up there and that fixed the problem.